# Iphone memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The following code snippet is from facebook.m file:

```
-(void) requestWithMethodName:(NSString *)methodName 
                andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params 
            andHttpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod 
              andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate {
    NSString * fullURL = [kRestApiURL stringByAppendingString:methodName];
    [self openUrl:fullURL params:params httpMethod:httpMethod delegate:delegate];
}
```

I have found a 100% memory leak in `fullURL` initialization line. I can't found solution for it..

If any one know solution for it then please help me.

Comment: Please put your code inside code snippet.

Comment: What have you done to find the solution? How are the NSStrings and Dictionaries, are they leaking?  You have given us very little to work on.

Comment: Then that means the `kRestApiURL stringByAppendingString:methodName]` call is causing the leak. What is the code for that method? My guess: it's returning an object that was not `autorelease` d.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a leak here. The `stringByAppendingString:` method returns a new string which is already added to the autorelease pool.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments finds the leak. It disappears if you get rid of the retain in the FBRequest class method

```
+ (FBRequest *)getRequestWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *) params
                         httpMethod:(NSString *) httpMethod
                           delegate:(id<FBRequestDelegate>) delegate
                         requestURL:(NSString *) url {
  FBRequest* request    = [[[FBRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    request.delegate      = [delegate retain]; 
    request.url           = [url retain];         // <----- no leak if you don't retain url
    request.httpMethod    = [httpMethod retain];
    request.params        = [params retain];
  request.connection    = nil;
  request.responseText  = nil;

  return request;
}
```

But here all seems to be ok for me, so I can't say if the bug is here or in Instruments. Suggestions?